# Will the average of a conditional sample converge in probability to the conditional expectation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-convergence

Suppose I have a random variable $X$ from which I sample $n$ times. Then I take the average of only those realizations that fullfill a certain condition $A$.

Will this average converge in probability to the conditional expecation?

$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1\\i \neq j}^{n} x_i \overset{P}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{E}[X|A]\quad j =\{i \in n | x_i \notin A \}
$$

Comment: Yes it will. To see this, introduce the i.i.d sequence $Y_i = \text{indicatorfunction}(A)*X_i$ and the random variable $\tau_n : = \text{number of occurences of A during the first n realizations of the } X_i$ and then look at the almost sure convergence of $\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i / \tau_n$.